# priority in software testing

Tags: manual-testing, bug-priority, bug-severity

If there is some misspelled or mistake in copywrite information then will that be of high priority and low severity or some other would be answer for this ?

Comment: "high priority and low severity" to whom? Value is subjective, one cannot say infer the value of something per se, but only under the point of view of a human.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy right is regulatory information so misspells and mistakes are of a high priority issue.

But severity depends on what kind of misspells and mistakes it has, if the misspells are just spelling mistakes that doesn't change the actual meaning of the content then its a low severity bug, on the other hand if the copyright date is wrong then its a high severity bug as the content gives the wrong emphasis that the copyright has been expired and the content is reusable without any restrictions.

**Note:** priority also might be medium if you have some other high priority functional/security issues that require more immediate attention than low severity issue

Comment: " are of a high priority issue..." to whom? Maybe the value of immediate delivery is higher than adhering to a specific regulation. Value is subjective, it cannot be assessed per see, but only through a specific person point of view.

Comment: @JoãoFarias thats the "Note" part copy right is regulatory information so it has more priority than functionality

Comment: if copy write date is wrong then it should be fixed immediately

Comment: @Downvoter Please add a helpful comment before downvoting,

Comment: @PDHide This answer seems confusing. "Copyright" and "Copywrite" are not the same thing. The first is a date and the second is written word on a page. The OP mentions "copywrite" and the answer mentions "copyright". Intermixing the two changes the meaning.

Comment: @LeeJensen Thanks for pointing it out but as ops haven't asked any question i think its a misspell (which changed the entire context)